# SyntaxError: Unexpected token export after angular4 + Universal

Tags: angular, npm, universal

I am stuck in making my nagular 4 with SEO friendly using Universal.

I have followed the steps as provided here. https://github.com/neoighodaro/Angular-SEO-friendly-example/blob/master/tutorial.md with my existing application.

If i create seperate application, i am getting perfect output.

But, when i am trying to integrate in existing ang4 it's throwing error.

I have resolved all the issues one by one. But

```
"ang\angular\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\modal\index.js:1
 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export { 
 BsModalRef } from './bs-modal-ref.service';
   ^^^^^^SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

this is my package.json

```
{
        "name": "angular2-cli",
        "version": "0.0.0",
        "license": "MIT",
        "scripts": {
          "prestart": "ng build -- eve=prod --aot=false && ngc",
          "start": "ts-node src/server.ts"
        },
        "private": true,
        "dependencies": {
          "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
          "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
          "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
          "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
          "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
          "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
          "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
          "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
          "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.0",
          "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
          "angular-2-local-storage": "^1.0.1",
          "angular2-busy": "^2.0.4",
          "angular2-emoji-picker": "1.4.3",
          "angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.3.5",
          "angular2-social-login": "^3.0.1",
          "core-js": "^2.4.1",
          "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
          "google-maps": "^3.2.1",
          "jquery": "^3.2.1",
          "lg-autoplay": "^1.0.4",
          "lg-fullscreen": "^1.0.1",
          "lg-hash": "^1.0.1",
          "lg-pager": "^1.0.2",
          "lg-share": "^1.0.2",
          "lg-thumbnail": "^1.0.3",
          "lg-video": "^1.0.1",
          "lg-zoom": "^1.0.4",
          "lightgallery": "^1.3.9",
          "lightgallery.js": "^1.0.1",
          "ng-cli": "^0.7.0",
          "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
          "ng2-go-top-button": "^2.0.8",
          "ng2-google-place-autocomplete": "^1.4.2",
          "ng2-toastr": "^4.0.1",
          "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
          "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
          "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.1",
          "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
          "time-ago-pipe": "^1.2.1",
          "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
          "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
          "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
          "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
          "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
          "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
          "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
          "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
          "karma": "~1.4.1",
          "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
          "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
          "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
          "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
          "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
          "protractor": "~5.1.0",
          "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
          "tslint": "~4.5.0",
          "typescript": "~2.2.0",
          "webpack": "^3.8.1"
        }
      }
```

This is my tsconfigapp.json:

```
   {
      "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "module": "es2015",
        "baseUrl": "",
        "types": []
      },
      "exclude": [
        "server.ts",
        "test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
      ]
    }
```

This is my tsconfig.json

```
         {
              "compileOnSave": false,
              "compilerOptions": {
                "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
                "baseUrl": "src",
                "sourceMap": true,
                "declaration": false,
                "moduleResolution": "node",
                "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
                "experimentalDecorators": true,
                "target": "es5",
                "typeRoots": [
                  "node_modules/@types"
                ],
                "lib": [
                  "es2016",
                  "dom"
                ]
              },
              "angularCompilerOptions": {                          

                "genDir": "./dist/ngfactory",
                "entryModule": "./src/app/app.module#AppModule"
              }
            }
```

i am stuck and i surfed all the internet and no perfect solution i got.

Please suggest me how can i resolve this error.

ERROR is:
[image]

Comment: Hi, did you solved your issue ?

Comment: hi user6250770 & @Kevin , did you solve your issue, I have exactly the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
{ BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

instead of this:

```
{ BsModalRef } from './bs-modal-ref.service';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this problem for a very long. I use to do a workaround to bypass this. But finally, I have fixed this. So, here is the solution.

### Where did I find this problem:

ngx-bootstrap

### Problem:

This npm package is written in ES6 and is not being transpiled to support older environments like ES5. So, it does not understand the keyword like `export` or `import`.

### Solution

To make the package compatible with our environment, we have to transpile it by ourselves. I did it using webpack and babel-loader to transpile ngx-bootstrap package.

#### Steps:

1. Get your universal build ready.
2. Install webpack and loaders packages related to babel using this command,

   `npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack`
3. Create a webpack configuration file `webpack.config.js`.
4. Add babel-loader like this, and exclude all other packages than `ngx-bootstrap`.

```js
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!ngx-bootstrap)/
      }
    ]
  }
```

To understand transpilation and what's going wrong in this issue, I would recommend you to read this nice article [How to transpile node modules](https://developer.epages.com/blog/coding/how-to-transpile-node-modules-with-babel-and-webpack-in-a-monorepo/).